# converting object to two dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, excel-interop

This one should be simple, but I don't really know how to find a way to do it...

I am using .NET 4.0. I have an `object[12]` filled with decimal numbers, and want to use it to fill an Excel range of `Double`s [1,12]. I am converting JSON using `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonData = javascriptSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>("{data:[0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22]}");
```

It should be a one-liner, but the only working thing I can come up with is:

```
var myArray = new Double[1, 12];
// the cast to Double is necessary as json data is of type decimal, however excel seems to only accepts Double here
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { PrimeShr[0,i] = (Double) jsonData["data"][i]; };
// sheet is of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
sheet.Range["myExcelRangeName"].Value2 = myArray;
```

or still rather pitiful, but at least in one line:

```
sheet.Range["Input_PremiumSHR"].Value2 = new Double[1, 12] { { (Double)jsonData["data"][0], (Double)jsonData["data"][1], (Double)jsonData["data"][2], (Double)jsonData["data"][3], (Double)jsonData["data"][4], (Double)jsonData["data"][5], (Double)jsonData["data"][6], (Double)jsonData["data"][7], (Double)jsonData["data"][8], (Double)jsonData["data"][9], (Double)jsonData["data"][10], (Double)jsonData["data"][11] } };
```

I'd expect something like that to work, but from what I gather initializers won't work this way :

```
sheet.Range["Input_PremiumSHR"].Value2 = new Double[1, 12] { new System.Collections.ArrayList( jsonData["data"] ).ToArray() };
```

I have quite a few similar cases (one with [12,1] which probably could be harder) and I don't want to struggle with each one that much. Is there a way to write it a bit more simpler?

Comment: What is the actual type of `jsonData` (as told by `GetType().FullName`)?

Comment: jsonData["data"] is System.Object[], but jsonData itself is of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension method that turns a single-dimensional array (or any other collection) into a 2D array with one column:

```
static T[,] ToColumn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var items = sequence.ToArray();

    var column = new T[1, items.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        column[0, i] = items[i];

    return column;
}
```

Using that you can write the code like this:

```
var data = (object[])jsonData["data"];

var column = data.Cast<decimal>().Select(x => (double)x).ToColumn();

sheet.Range["myExcelRangeName"].Value2 = column;
```

You *could* write that on one line, but I think that would hurt readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like an acceptable solution. If I'll be able to combine it with converting json to an explicit structure it'll be just `sheet.Range["myExcelRangeName"].Value2 = ToColumn(jsonData.data);`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you have to use dynamic? Why don't you make a simple class representing jsonData.

```
 public class SomeData
 {
      public double[] data { get; set; }
 }
```

Then after deserialization,

```
 JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var jsonData = javascriptSerializer.Deserialize<SomeData>("{data:[0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22]}");
```

you would be able to access jsonData.data directly.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer as well, as it's quite true, there's no sense in using dynamic here, it gets much less readable, and json should have some expected structure anyway. I'll probably use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = ((object[]) jsonData["data"]).ConvertAll<double>();
sheet.Range["Input_PremiumSHR"].Value2 = new double[1, values.Length] { values };
```

But I agree with Taesung that [explicit data structure would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905226/converting-object-to-two-dimensional-array-in-c/6905360#6905360).

Comment: Your code doesn't work. `ConvertAll()` requires two type arguments and you can't initialize array the way you do.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me "A nested array initializer is expected" as well? I think it does for me. Anyway, I'll probably try explicit data structure then.